# Getting error with Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am getting error or freezing when the application is running as its gives me message:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@Category" " next to dashowadscat.Fill(dsadsshowcat);`.

Also there is a red line under   QueryString["cat"]

```
  using (SqlConnection shwadscat = new SqlConnection(cs))
          {                   
            shwadscat.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter dashowadscat = 
              new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT [AdsID],
                                         [Section], 
                                         [Category], 
                                         [Country], 
                                         [State], 
                                         [City], 
                                         [AdsTit], 
                                         SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,155) as AdsDesc,
                                         [AdsPrice], 
                                         [Img1] 
                                  FROM [ads] 
                                  WHERE (([Category] = @Category) 
                                  AND ([Country] = @Country))", cs);

            string location = Convert.ToString(Session["location"]);
            string cat = Convert.ToString(QueryString["cat"]);

            DataSet dsadsshowcat = new DataSet();

            dashowadscat.Fill(dsadsshowcat);

            cateshowlistview.DataSource = dsadsshowcat.Tables[0];
            cateshowlistview.DataBind();
          }
        }
        else
        {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues...

- You need to specify values for the parameters in your query string.
- I assume you want `Request.QueryString`, not just `QueryString`, which doesn't mean anything by itself, which is why you're getting a syntax error.
- You're currently passing your `SqlDataAdapter` a connection string, instead of the `SqlConnection` you instantiated. If your connection string works for the `SqlDataAdapter`, then you can altogether remove the `SqlConnection` "shwadscat".

Try this:

```
var location = Convert.ToString(Session["location"]);
var cat = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["cat"]);

var dsadsshowcat = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection shwadscat = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    shwadscat.Open();

    using (var dashowadscat = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT AdsID, Section, Category, Country, State, City, AdsTit, SUBSTRING(AdsDesc,1,155) as AdsDesc, AdsPrice, Img1 FROM ads WHERE Category = @Category AND Country = @Country", shwadscat))
    {
        dashowadscat.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cat);
        dashowadscat.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", location);

        dashowadscat.Fill(dsadsshowcat);

        cateshowlistview.DataSource = dsadsshowcat.Tables[0];
        cateshowlistview.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Kudos for parameterizing your query  by the way. That's the more secure, more maintainable way to do it.

Comment: really thanks for your reply but i getting a red line under 'parameters'   Error 37 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'Parameters' and no extension method 'Parameters' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

The select statement requires 2 parameters in where clause and you did not provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SQL `SELECT DISTINCT [AdsID],[Section], [Category], [Country], [State], [City], [AdsTit], SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,155) as AdsDesc, [AdsPrice], [Img1] FROM [ads] WHERE (([Category] = @Category) AND ([Country] = @Country))`

I believe you want to pass `@Category` and `@Country` as parameter, you may check [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx), otherwise, you may concat your SQL in code like:

**Edit** (Expand the code with whole using, and change `cs` to `shwadscat`:

```
using (SqlConnection shwadscat = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    shwadscat.Open();

    string location = Convert.ToString(Session["location"]);
    string cat = Convert.ToString(QueryString["cat"]);

    SqlDataAdapter dashowadscat = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT [AdsID],[Section], [Category], [Country], [State], [City], [AdsTit], SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,155) as AdsDesc, [AdsPrice], [Img1] FROM [ads] WHERE (([Category] = '" + cat+ "') AND ([Country] = '" + location + "'))", shwadscat);

    DataSet dsadsshowcat = new DataSet();

    dashowadscat.Fill(dsadsshowcat);

    cateshowlistview.DataSource = dsadsshowcat.Tables[0];
    cateshowlistview.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply yes i want to use Category and Country as a parameter to show a specific ads depending on them, i have tried you sql statement but i still getting the error  Must declare the scalar variable "@Category" . i have used a sqldatasource and its work fine but i prefer to use server code, here is the sqldatasource code which is working fine i have added in my post

Comment: May you search your procedure for `@Category`? I think after you modified the sql, it should not have any `@Category` in your code. Beside, I found that you may use `shwadscat` as second parameter instead of `cs` in your `new SqlDataAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the scalar variable `@Category`, here's an example:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [AdsID],[Section], [Category], [Country], [State], [City], [AdsTit], SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,155) as AdsDesc, [AdsPrice], [Img1] FROM [ads] WHERE (([Category] = @Category) AND ([Country] = @Country))", cs);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = "";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = "";
```

Comment: Dear @stackCheck thanks for your reply but it doesnt work i getting a ling red line under the SqlCommand statement